# Requisição AJAX dá erro e status "canceled"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho esse código:

```
$("#go").click(function(){

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    $.ajax({
        dataType:'html',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password,
        url: 'login.php',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

que gera a seguinte requisição ao servidor:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/Snotes/login.php
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/Snotes/index.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
email:123
password:123
```

A url de requisição está correta e os dados também, mas a função de error é sempre chamada, na aba de network do chrome diz que a o status é 'canceled', alguém pode me ajudar com este erro?

Comment: o alerta de erro é executado? o que retorna na página de login.php?

Comment: caso a autenticação tenha sido feito ele retorna o id do usuário, caso contrário ele retorna 0, o script php escreve no corpo da página com 'echo' os valores citados

Comment: Se está caindo no callback `error` é porque está dando erro no php. Você postou os headers da requisição, verifique também os headers e o conteúdo da resposta, o erro vai aparecer lá.

Comment: Em response tá falando 'Failed to load response data', no entanto quando eu uso o debugger e vou executando até que o jQuery finalize o processo todo, a requisição funciona(chama success mas a aba response ainda possui a mesma mensagem de falha), e quando não debugo ela não funciona(chama error).

Comment: Qual response code está dando?

Comment: 'Failed to load response data' é  que aparece em response, com o método 'complete' eu peguei uma mensagem de error status onde o código do erro é 0 e a mensagem de error é simplesmente "error"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok problema resolvido, tive que adicionar um parâmetro à callback do click e usar  o método `.preventDefault()` no evento, para impedir o comportamento padrão que é submeter o form.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796947/jquery-ajax-function-not-working.

Agradeço a todos que ajudaram ;)

Código de solução.

```
$("#go").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#name").val() + "%20" + $("#last_name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url:  'new.php',
        data: 'name=' + name + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Failed to send data to server!");
        }
    });

});
```